# multiple GROUP BY to find more than one row based on WHERE condition

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table for timetable allocation for an institution. I have to figure out if there are more than one allocations in the same room in a single period meaning there shouldn't be any room with more than one allocation for a particular period.

Table structure with relevant fields for this question is as follows:

```
teacherid  subjectid groupname room  day  period 

  1           213        2       1    4      3
  2           123        4       1    5      3
```

and so on...

How can return those rooms with more than one allocations in a single period.

Comment: Do rows also have an id column?

Comment: @Bohemian oh yes they do.. how can i use them here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct room from table t1 where exists
(select count(*) c1 from table where t1.room = room 
and t1.day=day and t1.period = period having c1>1);
```

If day need not to be considered:

```
select distinct room from table t1 where exists
(select count(*) c1 from table where t1.room = room 
and t1.period = period having c1>1);
```

Comment: it was giving multiple rows for same room, i added a group by for room. is it correct?

Comment: yes there should be group by in the main query,i missed it. You may also add a distinct at begining

Comment: there is one thing though. i have encountered one room returned by the query which dont have any multiple allocations in any slot

Comment: the result set and sample data..!!

Comment: If it's still showing incorrect result (returning room without any multiple allocation), you may provide corresponding rows and result set in update here or provide a link up sqlfiddle(google it). BTW, the query should not produce wrong results.

Comment: Well, i used the one with the day and period both and it gave correct results while the one with just period as constraint was showing incorrect ones. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.room
from timetable t1
join timetable t2
    on t1.day = t2.day
    and t1.period = t2.period
    and t1.id > t2.id
```

The join is fairly straightforward - it finds rows with the sane day/period, but there is a trick in there worth noting... the last comparison in the join condition:

```
and t1.id > t2.id
```

This does two things:

1. Stops rows joining to themselves
2. Stops colliding rows from joining twice. Without the greater-than (or a less-than would work equally well) ie if it was `!=`, colliding rows would join once for each side of the join

You asked for just the rooms, but if you `select *` you'll get all the info about the collision.

Comment: this is giving me around 40000 rows when in reality the whole table just has some 2000 rows

Comment: but the above query is giving me 40000 rows. how is that correct/

Comment: Don't we have to use a group by clause here

Comment: No need for group by. Copy-paste the query. Note there is no WHERE clause either.

Comment: I have assumed that "same period" is when "day" and "period" are the same (that was all there was in the Q). Is there more to it than that?

Comment: Try adding `DISTINCT` after "select"